# Add New Item Dropdown box as combo Box

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

I have a client who would like a drop down list () in their add new item form to be a ComboBox.. The stupid thing is, it used to be a combo box but now its a drop down box, The difference being you cant write anything in the drop down box (making it search easier)..

I think it may be an Browser issue how it displays  but I haven't upgraded my browser and I use IE11..

Is there anything I have done in sharepoint that would have changed the way lookup fields are rendered when adding new items?

Answer (score 1):

You now have less than 20 items in the lookup list.

This is standard behavior for a lookup column. The moment you have 20 or more selectable items in the lookup list, then the UI changes from a simple dropdown to a type ahead combo box.

Comment: is this a sharepoint thing or a Internet explorer thing?  unfortunately its not right, I have over 300 items in the list

Comment: I think its somehow related to an error that I have just noticed ( and is new some how) SP.Publishing is undefined